# Session at Data.SE expires very quickly

Tags: feature-request, data-explorer, session

Subj. The expiration time is about 1 hour or so. This is very inconvenient:

- If I leave a query open, after some time it becomes inoperative - impossible to execute and the editor glitches
- I have to login every time - which I don't have to at other SE sites

Comment: I believe it's the default ASP.NET session timeout, which is 30 minutes.

Comment: @ShadowWizard it was sliding for sure, not fixed as it seems to be now

Comment: @rene well, SEDE moved servers few times, it was probably some long forgotten server setting, not something in the code.

Comment: @ShadowWizard anyway, the strong points in favor of the suggestion that I gave here are not mentioned in the duplicate, so I duplicated them there.