# Why do I have to log in again to https://data.stackexchange.com/ frequently?

Tags: support, data-explorer, login

I stay logged in on https://*.stackexchange.com for weeks except on https://data.stackexchange.com, where I have to log in again every few days. Why?

[image]

Comment: Does this answer your question? [SEDE logs me out more often than it used to do](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/287142/sede-logs-me-out-more-often-than-it-used-to-do)  There are a number of duplicate linked to that question.

Comment: @Ollie they're not asking exactly the same thing, that was suggesting a remedy, this is asking why it happens in the first place.

Comment: You're basically logged out once the app domain recycles. Can happen every 20 minutes of app inactivity (unlikely) , on high load, due to an crash or on a fixed schedule. If it happens multiple times per day, there is an issue. None of the cookies used on SEDE are restart re-silent. The login / auth system on SE proper is totally different and can deal with restarts/ webfarms etc.

Comment: A closer duplicate may be (not obvious by the title): *[Extend or remove Data Explorer timeout](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/182256)*. There are also *[Session at Data.SE expires very quickly](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/295093)* and *[SE Data Explorer always logs me out](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/301999)*.

Comment: Somewhat of [an explanation, and a fix](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/353406/282094).

Comment: There's [a relevant userscript on StackApps](https://stackapps.com/questions/8366/data-explorer-sede-auto-login-that-redirects-back-to-original-target-page) that will automatically login for you; I find it really handy for this problem.