# Log in problem via GitHub

Tags: discussion, support, auto-login, github

Generally I log into https://stackoverflow.com/ via GitHub, and I can access all my Stack Exchange network sites. I do not need to log in to all Stack Exchange network sites separately. But this thing always does not happen...

**Login Problem**

Sometimes I need to log in separately for a different Stack Exchange network site … that means after logging into the https://stackoverflow.com/ site via GitHub, I need to log in separately for other Stack Exchange network sites.
This is the problem I face sometimes.

Comment: I don't understand what the problem is. That you need to log in to each site? It's by design, that's how SE works.

Comment: Sometimes I need to log in separately for different network not always

Comment: Yes... because we have different domains, this is normal. The sites with stackexchange.com domains should generally only require a single login but for the sites like SO and SU, because they have their own domains most people have to log into them individually.

Comment: It depends on your cookie settings and browser. If you're using Safari then this will never work. If your browser does allow third party cookies it should also log you in on other sites, assuming [Universal Login](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/260153/global-auth-is-dead-long-live-universal-login) did its job ... if it didn't then you need to share more debugging info, specially which cookies you have and got set / were denied. The developer console of your browser could tell you that.

Comment: Can you add platform information to your question (***without*** "Edit:", "Update:", or similar - the question should appear as if it was written right now)? Browser name (incl. version), operating system (incl. version), relevant browser settings, relevant browser plugins in use ([uBlock Origin](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/UBlock_Origin)), etc.

Comment: @P.Mort. - forgot Clay Shirky_q Browser  google chrome and windows 7 & 10..

Answer (score 5):

This is [status-bydesign](/questions/tagged/status-bydesign).  Because Stack Exchange has different domains (mathoverflow.net, stackexchange.com, stackoverflow.com, superuser.com etc. etc. etc), you will sometimes have to log in to each domain individually.  If you have third-party cookies enabled, you *should* be able to login to all the domains with a single login (tested in Chrome and Firefox).

Comment: Still doesn't work for https://data.stackexchange.com/. I always have to login there ...

Comment: @DavidPostill The reason why that is can be found here: [Why do I have to log in again to https://data.stackexchange.com/ frequently?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/359564/why-do-i-have-to-log-in-again-to-https-data-stackexchange-com-frequently/359580#359580).

Comment: How can you call it status-bydesign if we have [Universal Login](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/260153/global-auth-is-dead-long-live-universal-login)? Either that feature got unshipped or there is a user site setting/restriction at play.

Comment: To Firefox, you can follow this [documentation](https://support.mozilla.org/en-US/kb/third-party-cookies-firefox-tracking-protection)